# How to preserve SEO value when building a completely new website?

Tags: seo

We have our existing website and from time to time we get leads from it, people say they reached us from Google.

Now, we are building a new website with a different wordpress template and we also 
 refreshed the content.

How can we check if we lose something on the way?
What actions do we need to take or tools we need to use in order to make sure we don't lose value?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry but this in addition to the question being too broad, it has already been asked in various forms on Pro Webmasters, one linked is one of many already on Pro Webmasters. We also have questions about changing designs, templates, themes, content management systems and even domains, please use the search function to find your desired related information.

Comment: Another related question [SEO impact of gradually changing design and text content](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88880/seo-impact-of-gradually-changing-design-and-text-content)

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing your template and content at the same time, I will imagine that a slight drop will happen.

There are free and paid for ways to track this. Essentially you will want to use a keyword position tool.

- [Moz](https://moz.com/tools/rank-tracker)
- [AHref](https://ahrefs.com/rank-tracker)
- [SEM Rush](https://www.semrush.com/lp/position-tracking-2/uk.html?kw=keywords_ranking&cmp=UK_SRCH_Website_Rank_EN&label=Position_Tracking&Network=g&gclid=CjsKDwjw95vPBRDVgarcl8PDcRIkAKvPd3IrvzIVJ-V95HBO15ABevpD0I6ryHRZeUQPsYqCeS7YGgIfEPD_BwE)

It would also be worthwhile checking your conversion rates for leads with a web analytics tool such as Google Analytics.